# Convert video using ffmpeg for watermark creation with multiple text

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to convert a video using **FFMPEG** and place a **watermark** with **multiple texts** on it. Combining the commands for placing a text and a watermark is :

`ffmpeg -i input_1.mp4 -i watermark_small.png -filter_complex "[0]overlay=10:10; [1]drawtext=enable='between(t,0,12)':fontfile=font.ttf:text='Some text' : fontcolor=black: fontsize=18: box=1: boxcolor=yellow@0.5:boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/1.15:y=30, drawtext=enable='between(t,14,22)':fontfile=font.ttf:text='Next text' : fontcolor=black: fontsize=18: box=1: boxcolor=yellow@0.5:boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/1.15:y=30" -codec:v libx264 -preset ultrafast output1.mp4`

Unfortunately this command puts the watermark and the first text but not the next text. I assume the problem is on -filter_complex setting. Unfortunately I don't know how to set it in the right way in order to work.  Could someone help me and say what needs to be changed in this command in order to convert it in the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
[0]overlay=10:10; [1]drawtext
```

To:

```
[0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10,drawtext
```

- Manually define input labels for filters instead of relying on defaults.
- Use `,` to linearly join filters that accept a single input and/or output. This creates a filterchain. Use `;` when you want to join filterchains. See [FFmpeg Filters Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) for more info.